# No data received on post request

Tags: php, android

My project contains a call `Network.SendLocation();` and the following class:

```
package com.example.getcurrentlocation;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy;
import android.util.Log;

public class Networking{

    public void SendLocation(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= 10) {
            ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
            }
        //Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/BW/Test.php");

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                // writing response to log
                Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
     }
}
```

For some reason, I cannot get any data back from the call (same goes for calling "http://www.google.com"). As well, the php never executes anything, so it's simply not hitting it. I can't figure out any reason why it wouldn't work. I have tested with toast before and after this entire call.

Comment: what does this log `Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());`

Comment: It is unneeded, but it longs the response from the server.

Comment: i see nothing wrong just try `String res = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());`

Comment: remove strictmode and use a thread or asynctask. Make sure all your network operation on the thread

Comment: If you try to connect local server means,You need to use "http : //10.0.2.2",try it

Comment: are you calling it from asynctask or main thread/

Comment: @appubala, PERFECT. Will you please write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android You need to connect the Local Server means you need to use "`http://10.0.2.2`" **or** "`http://YOUR SERVER IP`" instead of "`http://localhost:8080`"

Comment: Thanks, fixed all of my problems perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, this is my code for work.

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,HTTP.UTF_8));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
String state = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
Log.i("henry", "state = "+state);
```

and make sure your php have to echo something

```
<?PHP
    echo $_POST['id'];
?>
```